# Datatable - Fixed column not working after sorting in edge

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have 3 4 columns fixed in a jQuery datatable. After I click on sort (header), the fixed columns are lost. It only happens in Edge. Working OK in other browsers

Comment: I think a code example where the behavior can be reproduced in Edge is required here. Any errors in the Edge console?

Comment: No error, but I just notice that dataTables_scrollBody width changes to 6777 instead of 100%